# Bootstrap 4 toggle switch not working in vue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

Why bootstrap 4 toggle switch aren't working in my vuejs chrome extension?
I'm using this code to display some switches but they are not clickable. I've imported jquery and the bootstrap css and js files but still not working.

```
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Backup</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
    </div>
    
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">QR code</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2">
    </div>
```

Comment: Sounds like there's a separate error with loading the scripts. Use devtools of the popup to inspect the problem. The popup has its own devtools which you can open by right-clicking inside the popup.

Comment: Already did this step before post, and tehre's no error logged. I'm using a separate standalone tab, not popup.

Comment: Did you check [extensions](chrome://extensions/) page to see if your extension loaded with any errors? I tried to create a custom extension using the code from your question by including bootstrap from cdn and I see `Refused to load .. ` error in Chromes extension page for my extension.

Comment: @Suresh no, there is no error! Bootstrap is loaded correctly, it's css and js are imported from webpack inside the main.js file of my vue app! If there was any kind of error with css or js, I have got the error when I try to build the extension